# How do I write a slideToggle() function that is reusable on repeated HTML structure, using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I need help writing a piece of JQuery using the slideToggle(), that is reusable.

Scenario: I have this HTML that is repeated multiple times down the page:

```
<h3>title</h3>
<div>
<table...</table>
</div>
```

Here is what I have in terms of JQuery so far:

```
$('h3#im-selling').click(function() {
  $('div.im-selling').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

Is there a way of writing JQuery that targets the HTML structure rather than picking out id's and classes...hence making it reusable?

Any help is Greatly Appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the `<div>` relatively using [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/), like this:

```
$('h3').click(function() {
  $(this).next().slideToggle('slow');
});
```

[`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) is one of the [tree traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) available.

Comment: not sure here, but you'll probably need to specify that what you want the next div element.

Comment: Thanks Nick...that was super quick, much appreciated

Comment: @yoda - `.next()` does *only* the immediately next sibling *if* it matches the selector, you'd need `.nextAll("div:first")` to get the next `<div>` sibling if there's anything in-between :)

Comment: thanks, wasn't sure about that. Anyway, might be usefull to someone latter :)